# Regex pattern for DateTime Formats

Tags: c#, regex, datetime

How to use the regex pattern for the below DateTime Formats,

```
d - Short Date,
D - Long Date,
f - full date with time,
t - time,
s - time with seconds.
```

my regex pattern for parsing DateTime Formats is given below,

```
if ((System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(style.Format, @"([hmsAMPM][,][ hmsAMPM])|([hmsAMPM][-/][hmsAMPM])|([hmsAMPM][-:][hmsAMPM])|([hmsAMPM][-/](.*)[-/][hmsAMPM])|([hmsAMPM][\s][hmsAMPM])", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)) || (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(style.Format, @"([mdMy][,][ mdMy])|([mdMy][-/][mdMy])|([mdMy][-/](.*)[-/][mdMy])|([Mdy][\s][Mdy]|d|D|f|t|s)", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)))
```

Above Regex pattern does not accepts the mentioned date time formats. May i know how to match the mentioned Formats with the Regex pattern? Is there any generic regex pattern for matching DateTime Formats in C#?

Thanks in Advance,

Venkat

Comment: You can't use regex to get valid dates in different formats. You could use `DateTime.TryParse` or `TryParseExact` on the relevant substrings.

Comment: Maybe you should tell us what you're trying to achieve. What is the source here? If it's HTML you could use `HtmlAgilityPack` to find the relevant controls via tag-name, class or ID and then use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx) with all allowed formats as parameter to extract the date. If it's a CSV-file use a [csv parser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I tried with TryParseExact also like if(DateTime.TryParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToString(), "d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))